Is the cone of decomposable skew-symmetric tensor closed?
Let $\bigwedge^{p}V$ be the space of skew-symmetric tensors, if $\omega=\alpha_{1}\wedge...\wedge\alpha_{p}$, then we call it decomposable. Is the cone of decomposable skew-symmetric tensor a closed set?

Yes. It is better known as the cone over the Grassmannian $\mathbf{G}(p-1, V)$.
The Grassmannian is a projective variety which parametrizes $p$-dimensional vector subspaces of $V$, or, equivalently, $(p - 1)$-dimensional projective linear subspaces of the projective space $\mathbb{P}V$. A $p$-dimensional subspace of $V$ defines a point $[v_1 \wedge v_2 \wedge \dots \wedge v_p] \in \mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^pV)$ where $v_1, \dots, v_p$ is any basis of the subspace.
This is called the Plücker embedding of the Grassmannian. The set of all decomposable points is a closed projective variety, defined by degree $2$ equations called Plücker relations.

Thanks! I was thinking is there any elementary way to prove that? I mean by taking Cauchy sequence... Things like that?

I don't know a very easy way, you will need to use some construction of the Grassmannian.

Okay, actually I have learned Plucker embedding before. But it never occures to me that these two things a so closely related. It is a very beautiful proof. Thanks again.
